# How to implement MLAA (like SIMD-based approach by Intel)?

Tags: optimization, antialiasing, simd, intel

I'm looking for previously available public source code sample what was originally posted here https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/code-sample/morphological-antialiasing-mlaa-sample.html

But it seems the link under "Download project" is dead (also tried with consumer account). Tried everything, wayback machine, search, found nothing. It seems the name of the archive should be SAA.zip.

However it is possible to find unoptimised version, I'm very interested on the latest one what was much polished and extended with simd usage in every function. Some code snippets of the SSE-functions from the archive is present here under Intel® SSE Optimizations section (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/229353/MLAA-Efficiently-Moving-Antialiasing-from-the-GPU), but the download link is the same (leads to intel website).

From what I found in reviews MLAA consists of 3 steps:
"1. Look for discontinuities between specific image pixels. In some images, the larger gradient amplitudes are not edge points.
2. Determine the predetermined mode and determine the rendered image.
3. Perform color mixing processing on the inner and outer edges of the collar in a predetermined mode. Determine the corresponding template in the pattern."

Could you explain how to rewrite the missing parts with SIMD ? I need 2nd and 3rd especially (also please share the direct link or the archive).

PS don't need any GPU version alternative.

Comment: Also, it's fine to ask about implementations, but requests for resources (i.e. links to code archives, etc.) are not considered on-topic for this community.

Comment: You are asking for the community to either write code for you, or share links to copyrighted code?